# "Edit" POST has null values

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I am making an ASP.NET MVC 5 web app using EF6. Here is the Edit() method that I'm given when I add a controller:

```
// POST: Gift/Edit/5
// To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
// more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "ID,Name,Description,Link,Price")] Gift gift)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Entry(gift).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("View", "GiftList", new { id = gift.GiftList.ID });
    }
    return View(gift);
}
```

Here is the model for Gift:

```
public class Gift {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Link { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public virtual GiftList GiftList { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser Buyer { get; set; }
}
```

The problem I am having is that when I go to the edit page and save, I get an error because the Gift that is being passed to Edit() has a null value for GiftList.

The exception that is being thrown:

`System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

At the line:

`return RedirectToAction("View", "GiftList", new { id = gift.GiftList.ID });`

I tried adding "GiftList" to the Include section of parameters but the gift.GiftList was still null. This is the only area I have a problem with getting the gift.GiftList. I have a feeling this has something to do with what values are edited on the Edit webpage, but I haven't been able to find anything online about this. Is there any way I can easily get the GiftList from the Gift or will I have to do something like `db.Gifts.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == gift.ID).GiftList`?

Comment: You model does not appear to include a navigation property for `GiftList` (e.g. `public int GiftListID { get; set; }`)

Comment: db.Gifts.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == gift.ID).GiftList //Almost sure that gift.ID is 0

Comment: Can you note on which line the project is throwing the exception, and what the exception is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not posting `GiftList` data to the action method along with the `Gift` properties, there's no `GiftList` entity to assign to the `GiftList` property.

Load the entity from the database, update the properties with the action method parameter's properties, save back to database.

```
var g = db.Gifts.Find( gift.Id );
if( null == g )
{
    // entity not found
}
else
{
    g.Name = gift.Name;
    // repeat with all editable properties
}

db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: So I either have to add the GiftList to the POST data (which I wouldn't want to do?) or get the gift object from the database? Also, why would I want to manually set each property of the gift then save, rather than using the code that's provided when I create the controller?

Comment: well, the code that's provided when you create the controller isn't working, is it?  `GiftList` and `ApplicationUser` are missing; you can either provide them by posting it with the rest of the `Gift` properties or you can load the data from the DB - you can then update the entity loaded from the DB as I describe or you could update the missing nav properties of the action method parameter with data loaded from the DB.  One thing that you should think about is why is `ModelState.IsValid` resolves to true when it is not valid (hint: MVC doesn't know your nav property is required)

Comment: The code that's provided does work to edit all the properties of `Gift` that I'd like to be editable. What doesn't work is the redirect after the properties have been saved to the database.  I would like to understand why the `Gift` object that is being passed has a null value for `GiftList` and how I could pass it in, or if I need to query the database to get the ID for the GiftList.  As for `ModelState.IsValid`, when it actually saves to the database, the `Gift.GiftList` is not overwritten with null, so the fields that are passed in are valid, but `GiftList` just isn't passed in.

Comment: Ah, my mistake; `GiftList` is not required, you're simply accessing an uninitialized property, but the problem and solution(s) are the same: `gift.GiftList` is null because you're not posting the `GiftList` property along with your `Gift` edit, thus you must load it from the database or include that data in your post to the action method.